# Take automated Screenshot of emulator

Tags: android, automation, emulation

I want to take automated screenshots of a running emulator, e.g. every 10 seconds and then save them into a directory.

I found out that I can do screen capturing with DDMS, but only over the UI. Is there any console based scripting API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it on System side then take a look at [Android-DDMLIB](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/android4maven/wiki/ddmlib). And [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/) Also look at this tutorial [Android: How to take screenshots from command line](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=168).

Or if you want to do all this at android device side then you have to `root permission` and read the `device framebuffer` for it.

Comment: in the meantime i found: http://code.lardcave.net/entries/2009/07/27/132648/ thanks!

Comment: I recommended you to go through Droid@Screen a nice project for getting device screen..

Comment: yes but i need it in a shell / python script to take screenshots of my emulator. so the framebuffer is good enough

Comment: I think for android 3.0+ in some tablet its (fb0) not worked. May be I am wrong on that. Just try it and let me know what happen..

Comment: Ok, fine. Actually, this not works in my case with samsung galaxy tab 3.0.